# Is it possible to use like proxy forward on s3 website?

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, proxy, jekyll, forward

I'm planning to host s3 website with following DNS.

- S3 bucket name: `example.com`
- S3 endpoint: `example.com.s3-website.amazonaws.com`

I also want to separate manual page for my service:

- S3 bucket name: `manual`
- S3 endpoint: `manual.s3-website.amazonaws.com`

When I enter `example.com/manual`, it should forward all request to my manual S3 but URL should not be changed.

For example, when I access, `http://example.com/manual/en/index.html`,
it should show `manual.s3-website.amazonaws.com/en/index.html`
but the URL should not be changed.

I tried to use redirection rules of 'Static website hosting' of bucket properties, but it just redirects to the my manual page (it changed the url).

And I'm using jekyll, but it doesn't support proxy forward unlike nginx.

Is there anything solution, guide, or example to refer?

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible if you would use CloudFront. You don't have to change your S3-setup.

- create an origin for each bucket
- create a second Behavior for the manual path

And you're done.